# Algorithm for matching measured to known items

Tags: algorithm, matching

I have a set of measured items (m1, m2 m3... ) and a set of real items (r1, r2, r3...). The set of real items is larger than the measured (not all items are measured ) and I'm looking for an algorithm to pair a measured item to the closest real item. I have a function error(meas, real) that will compute how close a measured item is to the real item (returning a single float number, the lower the closer).

I have implemented a greedy algorithm that will get pairs with the minimum error, that is, I compute the error for every possible pair and get the pair that minimizes the error, remove them from their sets and repeat until I have matched every measured item.

This methods works, but I am looking for an algorithm that minimizes the sum of all error() of every pair.

I suppose this is a common problem and there are possibly several options to solve this. If that is the case, if you can provide links or names to look for it on the Internet, it would be great.

Comment: Can a real item be matched to only one measured item?  If so, then I recommend you look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

Comment: A measured item can be linked only to one real item, but some real items will remain unpaired, as they are more abundant. Thanks for the link, it looks interesting but I have to check if it is Ok to leave tasks (or people) unassigned (following the Wikipedia's example).

Comment: A possible workaround is to add additional fake measured items with a cost of zero for any matchings.

Comment: A very high cost, I suppose, so they are always discarded. The problem with that is that the number of measures is 100 or 1000 times smaller than the number of real items, but I think I can do a prefilter to discard most of them.

Comment: @siritinga There are more efficient if less convenient ways to extend the Hungarian algorithm. The total storage will be on the order of the number of measured and real items.

Comment: @siritinga did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In my opinion the problem resembles space partitioning problem, where given a set of points on a plane(generally you can solve problem for **k** dimensional space) you have to find a closes point to a queried point.</strike> [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)

**EDIT**

I can relate this problem to [minflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) problem:

> The minimum-cost flow problem is to find the cheapest possible way of sending a certain amount of flow through a flow network

So construct a graph with two distinct sets of nodes(removed some unnecessary parts). Every node from M is connected to every node from R. Weights of vertices are calculated by `error` function. [image: from Princeton online courses]

The task is to transport *d* value from *s* to *t* keeping the transportation value as low as possible. You have to modify the original problem to meet your needs. For example, every vertex from *s* to M should be used while transporting *d*, e.t.c

I'm not sure if this is the correct way, but it's worth considering

Comment: Yes, for the greedy algorithm in euclidean space, you can use kd-trees instead of computing distances for every pair. However, in this case the error() function is rather complex and not linear nor geometrical, and I was looking for a solution that minimizes the total error.

Comment: How large are the sets?

Comment: About 50 measurements to be paired with a set of about 5000 items.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! I'm not sure this is the best way to solve the problem, is rather different, because here a value _d_ is divided in the different branches, like current in a resistor network.

Comment: @siritinga You'd need an integral min-cost flow (which is doable because the LP is totally unimodular), but for this network you should be using the Hungarian algorithm instead.